# how to renew expired certificate with fastlane?

Tags: ios, certificate, circleci, fastlane

My iOS certificate is stored in GitHub and it is expired, the failure message in circleci progress is that ‘Your certificate 'xxxxxxx.cer' is not valid, please check end date and renew it if necessary’.

Do I need to create a new certificate, or download an existing one? I don’t remember how this was originally created, I thought it was done by Fastlane as part of the build.

But I don't know how to modify the Fastlane command, I have tried to add the 'cert', but it fails.

Comment: try command `fastlane match`.

Comment: What commands are you currently using?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use `fastlane match development` after deleting the development profiles and certificates from your git repo. Alternatively, you can delete everything from git repo and run `fastlane match`

If you do not care about existing profiles and certificates, just run `fastlane match nuke development` and `fastlane match nuke appstore`, then `fastlane match development` and `fastlane match appstore`. These commands will first delete everything from your git repo and apple developer portal and the next two commands will create everything on your apple developer portal and push them to your git repo.

Read up [this](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8487)

Comment: I just can't believe why match can't have an argument so it by default does exactly that for the specified profiles and certificates - it is a terrible manual process every time!

Answer (score 23):

**Before start ensure you got certificates repo in github**

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/

Clearing old certificates

```
fastlane match nuke development
fastlane match nuke distribution
```

After clearing, we need to re-create new certificates

```
fastlane match development
fastlane match appstore
```

and restart your Xcode

Comment: It is important to add that you have to **make sure to use the latest version of Fastlane or, the same version used by your CI/CD tool**, otherwise CI/CD may fail even after following the steps above.

Answer (score 9):

I renewed expired certificate by deleting it from the Git repository and then running [`fastlane match`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/). If you append `--force` it will also renew the profiles to use the new certificate.

Steps:

1. Delete expired certificate from Git repository.
2. Run `fastlane match development --force` to renew certificate and profiles. (Replace `development` with `appstore` or `adhoc` depending on your certificate type.

Answer (score 2):

I find the simplest way is to delete the expire .cer on Develop portal and run `match` again.

Comment: And mobileprovisions!

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter this issue if there is license agreement update,
from account owner go to : https://developer.apple.com/account and accept new added agreement.

[image: https://developer.apple.com/account]